# fan out process with aws sns/sqs and best practices

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have been reading recently into both AWS SQS and SNS.

What I would like to know is, what scenarios would you:

1. Use SNS topic and multiple subscribers (lambda functions)

OR

2. SNS topic to multiple SQS queues (each queue having one independent
   process/service worker) // similar to article here:
   https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/queues-and-notifications-now-best-friends/

Thanks,
Shane.

Answer (score 0):

You could use it for any single action that requires multiple independent actions. When working with integration systems on message often needs to be send to different systems and each requires a different format.

One simple example could be a processing of an order. The order comes in as an SNS action. You would than trigger multiple actions:

- Generate an order in your ERP system
- Generate an order confirmation send out via e-mail
- Generate an information email for the Key Account Manager notifying them of the sale.
- Generate an invoice in the accounting department.

Each of the steps can run independently, but is triggered by the same action.

You would use the forwarding to Lambda, if could be processed directly within the Lambda time limits. You would send longer lasting actions to a SQS queue so that these actions could be processed by a batch.

A simple Lambda example would be a user signing up:

- One Lambda creates the "Welcome New User E-Mail"
- A second Lambda would create the new account.

Comment: thanks for reply @udo. so are you saying you use sns and lambda subscribers for short lived tasks and sns to sqs when the queue consumers dictate how to consume?

Comment: @shanelee Lambda is limited to running 5 minutes and maybe not all your tasks can/should be running from a Lamba. If your generating a order for the ERP system requires you to install a full client on an EC2 instance, than you couldn't do that from a Lamba and would put that task in a SQS queue so that it can be processed from your EC2 instance.

Comment: But is that it @udo? What about durability and order of messages?